# Deserializing a json that contains an xml declaration

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following json string:

```json
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "UTF-8"
  },
  "USER_DETAILS": {
    "USER": {
      "USR_ID": "452",
      "USR_FIRST_NAME": "First name",
      "USR_LAST_NAME": "Last name"
  }
}
```

I'm deserializing it using Newtonsoft.Json:

```cs
dynamic resultJson2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyJsonString);
```

How am I supposed to access my data now?
I get something like this:

[image]

This doesn't work:

```cs
resultJson2[1].USER_LOGON.USER
```

Comment: Isn't the XML part a red herring of this question? This is literally a JSON document with two propertes: ?xml and USER_DETAILS. Deserialize and handle as normal. Don't be distracted by the XML property. It seems likely to be an artefact introduced by a dumb conversion from XML to JSON.

Comment: Also, I've removed your ASP.NET tag because the fact that you're making a web application is not relevant to this question. Please ensure that you only add relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON contains 2 properties - `xml` and `USER_DETAILS` (don't know why you have `USER_LOGON` in debug window, maybe some settings not shown in question).

So you can access e.g. `FIRST_NAME`:

```
var firstName = resultJson2.USER_DETAILS.USER.USR_FIRST_NAME; // or USER_LOGON instead of USER_DETAILS
```